# resource vs. resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a User model which has_one :blog.  In my routes.rb file I have `resource :blog`.  Why doesn't it create a path for `blog#show`?  Do I need to create one myself?  Otherwise how do I link_to `blog#show`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does create a path for `blog#show` - see the output of your routes by running `rake routes`. The route missing is `blog#index`, because there is only one to show.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources for more information on singular routes.